# makefile simplifying

Tags: c, makefile

Suppose we have client-server application, compiling by one makefile. Server uses libtask for parallel clients serving. Client uses ncurses for some graphic.
directory tree looks like this:

```
./
--bin/
--obj/
--src/
----client/*.c
----server/*.c
--makefile
```

So, here is makefile. Can we simplify it? I read some related questions on stackoverflow and I think it almost ideal, except of linking binaries, when we can see repeated commands. Some suggestions for style/cross-platform working will be useful. Thank you!

```
.PHONY: all clean

TASKLIB = -ltask
CURSESLIB = -lncurses
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -pedantic

bin = server client
obj_dir = obj
bin_dir = bin
ssource := src/server
csource := src/client
search_wildcard s := $(addsuffix /*.c, $(ssource))
search_wildcard c := $(addsuffix /*.c, $(csource))
sobjs = $(addprefix $(obj_dir)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(notdir $(wildcard $(search_wildcard s)))))
cobjs = $(addprefix $(obj_dir)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(notdir $(wildcard $(search_wildcard c)))))

all: $(bin)
    @echo "done!"

server: CFLAGS+=$(TASKLIB)
client: CFLAGS+=$(CURSESLIB)

clean:
    rm $(sobjs) $(cobjs) $(obj_dir)/*.d $(bin_dir)/client $(bin_dir)/server

VPATH := $(ssource) $(csource)

server: $(sobjs)
    @test -d $(bin_dir) || mkdir $(bin_dir)
    @echo "Linking $(@F)..."
    @$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(bin_dir)/$@

client: $(cobjs)
    @test -d $(bin_dir) || mkdir $(bin_dir)
    @echo "Linking $(@F)..."
    @$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(bin_dir)/$@

$(obj_dir)/%.o: %.c
    @test -d $(obj_dir) || mkdir $(obj_dir)
    @echo "Compiling $(@F)..."
    @$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c -MD -o $@

include $(wildcard $(obj_dir)/*.d)
```

Comment: @ElnazShahmehr, it is my course work, but I always try to write general makefiles for my code.

Comment: great,did you get your answer?

Comment: @ElnazShahmehr, I think yes. Do I need to close question or something?

Comment: just mark az answer, that you alredy did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably more general than you need to be: For example, I wouldn't make the directories configurable - that only makes sense for destinations of an `install` target.

Anyway, this is how I would write your makefile (untested):

```
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -pedantic
RM := rm -f
MKDIR := mkdir -p

BINARIES := bin/server bin/client
SERVER_OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(wildcard src/server/*.c))
CLIENT_OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.c, obj/%.o, $(wildcard src/client/*.c))
OBJECTS := $(SERVER_OBJECTS) $(CLIENT_OBJECTS)

.PHONY : build clean realclean

build : $(BINARIES)

clean :
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

realclean : clean
    $(RM) $(BINARIES)

bin/server : LDLIBS := -ltask
bin/client : LDLIBS := -lncurses

bin/server : $(SERVER_OBJECTS)
bin/client : $(CLIENT_OBJECTS)

$(BINARIES) :
    @$(MKDIR) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

include $(wildcard obj/*.d)

$(OBJECTS) : obj/%.o : src/%.c
    @$(MKDIR) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -MD -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thank you, @Christoph. I like it more than my makefile.

Answer (score 0):

CMake is a cross-platform build system generator. Projects specify their build process with platform-independent CMake listfiles included in each directory of a source tree with the name CMakeLists.txt. Users build a project by using CMake to generate a build system for a native tool on their platform.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.4docs.html

http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmake

maybe this help you

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments:

- Add $(obj_dir) to the recipes for server and client.  As it stands, each time you run make it will rebuild the binaries.
- Add a recipe to make the directories (bin and obj) and remove them from the client & server recipes
- $< should be $^ for server and client recipe
- Clean by removing bin/ and obj/
- Perhaps use -MMD instead of -MD to exclude system dependencies
- Add more warnings to CFLAGS
- Should LDFLAGS be used for linking instead of CFLAGS
- If the same file name is used in both the server and client directories, build will fail.

Here are the lines I have changed:

```
all: $(bin_dir) $(obj_dir) $(bin_dir)/server $(bin_dir)/client
    @echo "done!"

clean:
    rm -rf $(obj_dir) $(bin_dir)

$(bin_dir) $(obj_dir) :
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@

$(bin_dir)/server: $(sobjs)
    $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(bin_dir)/client: $(cobjs)
    $(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(obj_dir)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c -MMD -o $@
```

You can also combine the server and client recipes into one, as Christoph shows.  My guess is that it can be made smaller by an expert, but sadly I'm not one.  The `$(sobjs)` and `$(cobjs)` look especially ripe for reduction.